# Linq Where clause returns everything even though I am filtering out a condition

Tags: c#, linq, solr, solrnet

I am using c# and SolrNet to return a list of games that gamers are playing.

In my c# code, I am trying to return data for `PlayerHistory`, where `IsPlaying` is true.

The database has a table for Players with a bit column (0 for false, 1 for true) for `IsPlaying`.

Here is my code:

```
var nodes = GetGamerNodes().Select(MapNode);
    Solr.AddRange(nodes);
    Solr.Commit();

private static SearchNodes MapNode(GameList node)
{
    return new SearchNodes {
        Id = node.Id.ToString(),
        GameTitle = node.Title,
        Story = node.Story,
        Published = node.Game.Published,
        PlayerHistory= node.Players.Where(e => e.Player.Current.IsPlaying).Select(e => e.Player.Name).ToArray()
    };
}
```

`PlayerHistory` is an `ICollection`

In my model, `IsPlaying` is defined like this:

`public virtual bool IsPlaying { get; set; }`

But it is returning `PlayerHistory` data for everything regardless of the value of `IsPlaying`.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a little trick that has helped me at times like these.

What works for me is to make a temporary predicate like this:

```
bool debugGetIsPlayerPlaying(Player player)
{
    return player.Current.IsPlaying;
}
```

and then when you do this replacement...

```
private static SearchNodes MapNode(GameList node)
{
    return new SearchNodes
    {
        Id = node.Id.ToString(),
        GameTitle = node.Title,
        Story = node.Story,
        Published = node.Game.Published,
        PlayerHistory = node.Players.Where(e => debugGetIsPlayerPlaying(e.Player)).Select(e => e.Player.Name).ToArray()
    };            
}
```

... it gives you something you can set breakpoints on and step through to help you determine exactly what's going on in the failing Linq query. Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Do you put the DebugPlayerIsPlaying in the model? Thanks

Comment: It's a static method (even though I didn't mark it as such) and can really go almost anywhere. But what I would do personally is make it a local method inside your SearchNodes method. Or right below it, either way.

Comment: Just curious, but why would this work? It seems to be doing the same thing with extra steps?

Comment: Right, yes, true. It's a matter of convenience, really because the root cause seems to be that player.Current.IsPlaying is always returning **true** and the mystery is why is that?  Another place to set a break point would be in the IsPlaying getter. The main point is that Linq is always iterating some enumerator somewhere and what's the fastest way to set a break point in that loop? I sure don't see any issue with the way you wrote the query itself looks good to me!

Comment: Now _I'm_ curious!! If node.Players is a list of Players then 'e' in your expression already is a Player. If we change the name of 'e' to 'player' then the  original query becomes node.Players.Where(player =>player.Player.Current.IsPlaying). So is player.Player something that makes sense? I'm actually really rooting for you to figure this out... :)

Comment: I know the names don't make sense...but  `Players` is an IEnumerable of `NodePlayer` and `e` is a `NodePlayer`.  I can see this when I hover over the code in Visual Studio.